# Mongodb Search comma separated string and diacriticInsentive search

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have the a document which has the following structure

```
{
     _id: ObjectId('$id'),
     authors: [{name: 'sample, náme'}]
},
{
     _id: ObjectId('$anotherId),
     authors: {name: 'sample 2, namé2'}
}
```

I have more properties but my problem is related to this one.

And I have the following query structure:

```
{
    $match: {
        'authors.name': {$regex: '.*$TextToMatchAuthorsName.*', $options: i}
    }
}
```

Now if I search using `sample` I get back the two documents, but if I change it to `sample name` there aren't any results back because of the comma or because of the accent. How can I make return result ignoring the comma or the accents that are in the words.

I would like to clarify that this is for an app I am designing, and our users will be typing in a searchbar.

Comment: Search for `sample.*n[aá]m[eé]`

Comment: @AlexBlex Yeah I know I can do that, but the users won't place that

Comment: diacriticInsentive is available to `$text` but not to regular expressions without the "chicanery" already mentioned. So you can either construct a regular expression with the "expected" diacritic substitutions based on the supplied text externally, or if you are not matching "partial words" then `$text` may be a viable option.

Comment: Similar goes for "caseInsensitive". You can set that collation on an index in modern MongoDB releases, but a "regular expression" does not use it without it's own `i` modifier. That's basically by design to not specifically break regular expression semantics

Comment: Ok, thanks. But What about the comma inside the string? The users in charge of inserting the data will include the comma, but for the other type of users they will query the data without it.